# Can't send direct message to Slack bot, feature turned off

Tags: slack

I created a Slack bot (app) and I'm not able to send direct messages to it even though I'm pretty sure I have all the permissions enabled.

The direct message window shows **Sending messages to this app has been turned off.** in the input field.

[image: Sending messages to this app has been turned off.]

Am I missing some permissions?

[image: Permissions]

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Go to your App Settings page and go to App Home and set the checkbox for "Allow users to send Slash commands and messages from the messages tab"
[image]

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/bot-docs/issues/2077#issuecomment-843960695

At the bottom you will see the option

[image]

Comment: It is worth noting that Slack client might need to be reloaded with `Ctrl+R` or `Cmd+R` (for Mac) for the changes to be seen, after you've granted all necessary permissions

Comment: Sadly that method has been deprecated - it's all down to scopes, with little help in getting it to work.  Actually, it suggests here :-  https://api.slack.com/messaging/retrieving "In a raw state, your app will only be able to view messages that are sent to it. " - that's clearly wrong as my default bot has "sending messages to this app has been turned off." in slack

Comment: Note: You need "Allow users to send Slash commands and messages from the messages tab" checked, even if you don't plan on using slash commands

Answer (score 8):

Adding following scope worked for me:

```
1. mpim:write   -> Start group direct messages with people
2. im:write     -> Start direct messages with people
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also update your app manifest file and add the features appHome option

```
  features: {
    appHome: {
      messagesTabEnabled: true,
      messagesTabReadOnlyEnabled: false,
    },
  },
```