# Slack Apps created using the CLI can only be managed through the CLI

Tags: slack, slack-api, deno

I'm trying to setup an app which is a replica of this [sample app](https://github.com/slack-samples/deno-timesheet-approval). It works great when I do `slack run` using the the Slack Deno SDK (Slack CLI v2.9.0). However, when I do `slack deploy`, it doesn't work as expected.

Since I changed the workflow a bit, I require the app to take in messages in a DM and based on the message time and content, check in or check out a user. In the dev/local version, I would have to go to the App Settings as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67674145/1334174) and allow user to DM the bot. But there is no such page for the deployed app (even though there's one for the dev/local app). It says "There's a glitch" (404, not a permissioning issue). Moreover, the manifest updates seemingly by itself. I tried to update it to the following:

```
  features: {
    app_home: {
      home_tab_enabled: true,
      messages_tab_enabled: true,
      messages_tab_read_only_enabled: false,
    }
  }
```

However, the updates do not reflect this change (the latter read_only option is always true). I'm thoroughly confused. May be an RTFM issue but please point me in the direction in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone named Declan at Slack helped me out with this. Changing this part of my manifest made all the difference:

```
features: {
    appHome: {
      messagesTabEnabled: true,
      messagesTabReadOnlyEnabled: false,
    },
  }
```